# Как сделать счетчик скачек файла?

Tags: php, html

Мне нужен счетчик скачек файла,который будет передавать информацию о скачках в другой файл с расширением php
Есть вот такой код,но он способен передавать кол-во скачек только в txt файл

```html
<?php
 if ($_GET['book']==1) {
  header("location: /zip.zip"); //здесь указываете путь к файлу, который нужно скачать
  $file=fopen("book.txt","a+"); //book.txt - это имя файла, в котором будет хранится статистика закачек
  flock($file,LOCK_EX); 
  $count=fread($file,100);
  $count++; 
  ftruncate($file,0); 
  fwrite($file,$count); 
  flock($file,LOCK_UN); 
  fclose($file); 
 }
?>
```

И страница с самим файлом

```html
<a href="bot/counter.php?book=1">Скачать файл 1 </a>
```

Пробовал вместо txt подключать php,но ничего туда не передается.

Comment: Что значит "передавать информацию в файл с расширением php"?

Comment: А в этом php файле вы что с этим числом будете делать? Записывать в базу данных?

Comment: нет,просто он будет записан в php страницу просто как текст,база данных не подключена

Comment: мне нужно,чтобы просто эта цифра добавлялась на страницу php,но содержимое той страницы php не нарушалось(а то у меня 1 раз получилось,но там просто вместо содержимого страницы php была одна цифра и все)

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую в php писать не самая лучшая идея. Всё же лучше в БД, ну или в какой-нибудь файл. Иначе это число будет для каждого пользователя или каждого обновления страницы обнуляться. Читаем матчасть, как работает PHP и понимаем, что от БД нам не уйти